# How do I traverse model data in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-select2, ui-select2

I have a dropdown with a backing JSON like this:

```
$scope.tradestyles = [
    {"id":"1","source":"Source One","name":"Name One"},
    {"id":"2","source":"Source Two","name":"Name Two"}
]
```

This is the dropdown, using `select2`, the model is the ID of the selected tradestyle:

```
<select id="tradestyle" ui-select2 ng-model="currentTradestyle" >
    <option ng-repeat="tradestyle in tradestyles" value="{{tradestyle.id}}">
        {{tradestyle.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Next to it, I want to place a text field where the selected tradestyle's name is shown and
can be edited.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="currentTradestyle" />
```

How do I change the model of the latter to point to the selected tradestyle's name rather than the ID? In other words, how do I traverse the scope object to point to the sibling name value of the selected ID value?

Answer (score 2):

If i have understood your question correctly, you need to use `ng-options` for binding to a object rather than a field. So it becomes

```
 <select id="tradestyle" ui-select2 ng-model="currentTradestyle" ng-options="style.name for style in tradestyles">

        </select>
 <input type="text" ng-model="currentTradestyle.id" />
 <input type="text" ng-model="currentTradestyle.name" />
```

See my fiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/UsfF6/

Comment: Thanks, but ui-select2 is incompatible with ng-options. I hope to get an answer that is compatible with ui-select2.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you can try `ng-click` over the `option` `ng-repeat` and manually select the item in controller.

Comment: If you put a ng-click in an ng-repeat you are going to create as many  event handlers as elements you've got in that repeat, I don't think it's a valid solution.

Comment: Something like this `ng-click="currentTradestyle=tradestyle"`

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
        <select id="tradestyle" ng-model="currentTradestyle" update-model="tradestyles">
            <option ng-repeat="style in tradestyles" value="{{style.id}}">{{style.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" ng-model="currentTradestyle.name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.tradestyles = [{
        "id": "1",
        "source": "Source One",
        "name": "Name One"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "source": "Source Two",
        "name": "Name Two"
    }];
}]);


app.directive('updateModel', function() {
    return {
       require: '?ngModel',
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
           function parser(value) {
               if(value) {
                   return _.findWhere(scope[attrs.updateModel], {id: value});
               }
           }
           modelCtrl.$parsers.push(parser);
       },
    }
});
```

This might satisfy the issues you raised in your comment. It uses tradestyle.id rather than $index in the `<option>`s which means the selected item works in cases where a filter is applied to the collection. The additional of a $parser ensures the tradestyle.id actually becomes the selected tradestyle item before being applied to the currentTradestyle model property.

Theres a dependency on Underscore but you can remove that with a more long hand alternative to the findWhere() method.

http://jsfiddle.net/asperry1/Zfecq/6/

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
        <select id="tradestyle" ui-select2 ng-model="currentTsIndex">
            <option ng-repeat="tradestyle in tradestyles" value="{{$index}}">{{tradestyle.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" ng-model="tradestyles[currentTsIndex].name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wawyed/UsfF6/8/):

Comment: Thanks, that should work in my situation. I would find it more elegant to use the IDs as dropdown values, and `currentTradestyle.name` looks nicer than `tradestyles[currentTsIndex].name`, but I don't want to be religious about that.

Comment: Another problem that I'm having is that Angular can't keep track of the changes I make in the edit fields, and updates the dropdown later instead of synchronous with my typing.

Comment: must be a ui-select2 issue